# Load data from an Array into a Spinner

Tags: java, android, android-spinner

I make a call to the server and the server give's me a response in Array format [Voters, Passport, DriversLicense, SocialSecurity]. I want to add the items to a Spinner so that a user can select one item at a time from the Spinner.

This is my code below:

```
public void loadIdTypes() {
    mAPIService.loadIdTypes().enqueue(new Callback<IdType>(){
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Response<IdType> response, Retrofit retrofit) {
            String name = response.body().getData().toString();
            Log.i("cityName", name);

        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Throwable t) {

        }
    });
}
```

Comment: can you add an example of the response string you're getting?
then someone can give you a full example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose that IdType is the Array you are talking about. If that so then you just need to create an Adapter for your spinner like below:

First, initialize the spinner in the onCreate method if you are using it inside an Activity or in onViewCreated if you are using a Fragment:

```
Spinner s = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.Spinner01);
```

Then inside your callback you should do the following:

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(context,
        android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, response.body().getData());
s.setAdapter(adapter);
```

You can pass the context as parameter to the method "loadIdTypes". If that code is being used inside an Activity just use MyActivity.this. If you are using it inside a Fragment just call getContext(). 
The layout called "android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item" is just a default layout, you can use the layout you want.
The third parameter is expected to be an array or a List.

For more information you can check the [official example](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/spinner.html)